# Issues installing ruby on osx 10.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, homebrew

Guys i am try to install ruby on mac using guides from this site `http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/`
but when i issues following commands on mac terminal:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enable
```

i am getting following errors:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Already up-to-date.
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, libyaml, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl, sqlite................................
Error running 'requirements_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config libyaml readline libxml2 libxslt libksba openssl sqlite',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_libyaml_readline_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl_sqlite.log
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
```

I tried many ways to get rid of this but i had no clues at all. Does anyone can help out to sort this issues? Thanks

Comment: Install Homebrew. `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"`

Comment: What does the log at `/usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_libyaml_readline_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl_sqlite.log` say?

Comment: @HungryCoder homebrew already installed

Comment: @AlexMarchant ==> Pouring pkg-config-0.28.mountain_lion.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28: 10 files, 636K
==> Downloading http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libyaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.4
==> make install
Error: Operation already in progress for readline
Another active Homebrew process is already using readline.
Please wait for it to finish or terminate it to continue.
  /usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.4: 7 files, 336K, built in 8 seconds

Comment: @HungryCoder I'm not sure what the problem is. I'd try the script again. You can also try running it with `sudo ` in front. And double check that `brew doctor` is registering OK.

Comment: avoid `sudo` it's not recommended by RVM and discouraged by Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue as well. It turned out that I had installed rvm in multi-user mode, and it was trying to run brew as root, which brew doesn't seem to like. In the error logs, I saw something like below:

```
[2013-04-04 11:40:12] requirements_brew_libs_install
Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install'
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at 
your own risk.
```

I fully uninstalled RVM (sudo rvm implode), then installed it just for the current user, and things went smoothly after that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest Xcode and have Command Line Tools installed through [Xcode Preferences] -> [Downloads]

If you have trouble installing again, install rvm this way:

```
$ curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```